# SSL in spring boot application using certificate file (.crt) and private key file (.key)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

To start with, we have two java applications.

One is traditional web app, generates war file which gets deployed in tomcat.

Another is spring boot application which generates jar file.

For SSL we have been provided with certificate file (.crt) and private key file (.key) files.

SSL has already been implemented for traditional application. It has been done by updating the `server.xml` file by adding below section and has been working successfully.

**server.xml**

```xml
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="/usr/local/tomcat/xyz-domain.key"
                     certificateFile="/usr/local/tomcat/xyz-domain.crt"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

I want to implement the similar thing for Spring boot application for embedded tomcat.

I have gone through many tutorials. All say things about .p12 format or .jks and to create some keystore from these files etc. I am bit confused now.

Can we follow the above xml section and configure embedded tomcat to behave same as traditional tomcat?
Or are there any limitations for embedded tomcat?

I followed below tutorial without success. 
https://github.com/craig-rueda/tomcat-native-spring-boot-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/tcnativeapp/TcnativeappApplication.java

Comment: Hope it helps for https://github.com/kprasad99/spring-boot-webflux-k8s-http2-example  refer certificate section.  The it's done for webfux. But it shouldn't matter

Comment: You should add property server.ssl.key-store= "/jks/keystore.jks"
 and server.ssl.key-store-password